# Connecting to oracle enterprise 11 from eclipse with Service Name

Tags: database, eclipse, oracle, jpa, connection

I would like to connect to Oracle 11g Enterprise DB from eclipse as part of JPA Project. I have service name, U/P and Hostname. But the option provided for me in eclipse is SID, which I do not have.

I use SQL Developer to connect to database and it works perfectly. 
I am not sure how to connect from eclipse with Service Name. any help?
I tried to give Service Name for SID. It didn't work.

Jar I am using is ojdbc14.jar. Not sure if this is the right Jar.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **"Generic JDBC"** connection profile and specify url directly: 
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/service_name`

Answer (score 2):

While creating a New Database connection you can also fix this by using 'Other Driver' instead of the Oracle JDBC Thin Driver. But, while adding the 'Drivers' in the 'Connection Profile' you have to add the same ojdbc jar that you usually use and add whatever properties in the 'Properties' tab of the 'New Driver Definition' keeps asking you for. 
The first error you may get is:  Required property in driver definition missing value: Driver Class.

Answer (score 0):

`SID` or system identifier is created when you install `oracle11g` in your system. It is always there.

I would suggest you to `Edit Connection` on `Sql Developer` and look for `SID`, it has to be there.

Alternatively you would have a `tnsnames.ora` file located at `ORACLE_HOME` > `Network` > `Admin`, it looks somewhat as follows:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host)(PORT = XXXX))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host)(PORT = XXXX))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Lookout for `SERVICE_NAME=orcl` on the last 3rd line, here in `orcl` is your `SID`, which you should be using to connect to `oracle` from `eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the fully qualified connection URL as shown below. 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the driver to ojdbc6

1. -click on the ojdbc14.jar and choose remover
 2. click add jar and browse to the location u downloaded it orcaleDB then follow the that path "\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\jdbc\lib"

 3. choose the ojdbc6 driver  and exit out